# error: expected expression when initialising a two dimensional structure variable in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, struct, compiler-errors

So I am trying to learn about structures in C and tried having a 2D character array in a structure. When I try to initialise it in main, I get an error saying "error: expected expression".

```
struct students
{
    char roll_no[9][2];
}st;
int main()
{
    st.roll_no={"21BCD7001","21BCD7002"}; //this is where I get the error
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error at the first '{' in main().So how do i remove this error?

Comment: @DavidRanieri i still get the same error on doing that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char roll_no[9][2];` means "give me 9 arrays, each 2 characters long". But you actually want 2 arrays, each 10 characters long. 9 bytes for the data and 1 byte for the null terminator. That is:

```
char roll_no [2][10];
```

Additionally, `st.roll_no={"21BCD7001","21BCD7002"};` is assignment not initialization. You cannot assign arrays in C, you'd have to use `strcpy` in this case. To actually initialize the struct, you will have to do this:

```
struct students
{
    char roll_no[2][10];
};

int main()
{
  struct students st = {"21BCD7001","21BCD7002"}; 
}
```

Or you can use the functionally equivalent but much prettier style:

```
struct students st = 
{ 
  .roll_no = {"21BCD7001","21BCD7002"} 
};
```

Comment: ok ya thanks that worked. Also what if I have two 2D arrays like this in my structure?

Comment: @Ppp The preferably go with the prettier style I just posted: `struct students st = 
  { 
    .first_array  = { ... },
    .second_array = { ... },
  }; `

Answer (score -1):

try removing st.(trust me I have 40 years of experience, I'm one if the core founders of java)